# Error in documentation, or bug in .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, .net-4.0

I recently was looking up how to open a file browser dialog box, when I came across [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Now, looking down at the example, it shows:

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

However, if I type that out, Intellisense doesn't recognize the `OK`. In fact, its not even an option. I'm having to use :

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)
```

Am I missing something stupid, or is this an oversight in the documentation?

Comment: Added both WPF and WinForms tags as the question is actually about mismatch between 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for the documentation for the Windows Forms [`Form.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method.

I suspect you're actually *using* WPF, where [`Window.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) returns a `Nullable<bool>`.

Comment: It's true, I'm using WPF. Didn't think that would matter, but apparently it does. And now I feel utterly stupid. :( lol. Thanks.